# Values list vs Iterating

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have to extract value of id field from each model instance in queryset. What is more efficient - iterating through queryset with use of list comprehension or values list method with flat argument setted to true and then converted to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values_list` will be more performant as it will only fetch the requested fields from the database and it will not instantiate model instances.

Quoting the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values):

> It is useful when you know you’re only going to need values from a small number of the available fields and you won’t need the functionality of a model instance object. It’s more efficient to select only the fields you need to use.